# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox xpath on previous result

Tags: perl, xpath, mechanize, www-mechanize-firefox

Can I execute a XPath query on previous result?
I have this xpath:

```
my @objDivRes = $objBrow->xpath('//div[@id="result"]/ol/div/li', all => 1);
```

but when I execute xpath function on previous result

```
my @objLink = $objDivRes[0]->MozRepl::RemoteObject::Methods::xpath('//div/h3/a');
```

I got an error:

```
MozRepl::RemoteObject: TypeError: doc.evaluate is not a function at test.pl
```

Is there an example? Thank you

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, The syntax is valid, though it's rarely used outside of `$self->SUPER::method()`. It does look it's [expected](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MozRepl::RemoteObject::Methods) in this situation. (Basically, it's to avoid injecting `xpath` is a number of other classes.)

Comment: @ikegami Well, I learned something today.

Comment: Have you tried forcing the return type of the `xpath` method as described in the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox#mech-xpath-query-options), e.g. `my @objDivRes = $objBrow->xpath('//div[@id="result"]/ol/div/li', all => 1, type => $objBrow->xpathResult('ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE') );`

Comment: The [docs for MozRepl::RemoteObject::Methods](https://metacpan.org/pod/MozRepl::RemoteObject::Methods#obj-MozRepl::RemoteObject::Methods::xpath-query-ref-cont) say that `MozRepl::RemoteObject::Methods::xpath` should only be called on `HTMLdocument` nodes, so perhaps a type mismatch is causing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just use 'node' option to set up a subtree [$mech->xpath( $query, %options )](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.76/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm#$mech-%3Expath(_$query,_%25options_))

Note **dot** in the beginning of the path, which means descendands of the context node

```
my @objDivRes = $objBrow->xpath('//div[@id="result"]/ol/div/li', all => 1);

my @objLink = $objBrow->xpath('.//div/h3/a', node => $objDivRes[0]);
```